# PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex.internalPointer() is not working, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I need to access and edit a complex data structure via a gui. The data is organized as a tree structure. The individual nodes form data sets, which are partly organized differently. To navigate through the data structure I use a tree view. For the selected dataset in the tree view (the selected item), I open a separate view with which this particular dataset can be edited.
For the tree view I implemented my own model by subcalssing `QAbstractItemModel`. To access the individual datasets I implemented my own classes as tree items. The tree view can be populized with the items and shows the surface data structure correctly.

Now I want to access the datasets via the model. For this purpose I call `QItemIndex.internalPointer()`. This call causes a crash of the application without throwing an exception.
While debugging, I kept reducing the complexity of my source code. Even using `QStandardItemModel` and `QStandardItem`, the crash persistently occurs.

I made a simple code example which demonstrates the error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
   import sys
   from PySide6 import QtGui, QtWidgets
   
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
   model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
   item = QtGui.QStandardItem('item')
   model.appendRow(item)
   tree.setModel(model)
   tree.show()
   
   # this works
   print(item.index().constInternalPointer())
   
   # this crashes
   print(item.index().internalPointer())
   
   sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Why do you need to access the internal pointer? That is normally required only in custom model access including index creation, data mapping, etc, something QStandardItemModel already does on its own. Also, its QTreeView.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't really clarify what you're going to do with it. If you're using a custom subclass for items too, then just use item prototypes, otherwise all methods of items are already available by accessing the items themselves. Also, the purposes of those different functions is to provide different types of objects depending on the needs, which is much more specific in C++.

Comment: [QStandardItemModel.setItemPrototype()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstandarditemmodel.html#setItemPrototype).

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. Are you trying to implement your own QAbstractItemModel subclass using an "internal" QStandardItemModel? If that's the case, it's a terrible idea. Otherwise, please try to be more clear in what you're actually trying to achieve and how you're specifically doing it (especially the "should be showed/edited in a own different view" which is very confusing)

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for your input. I rephrased the question.